# Next JS Project doesn't build when href is passed to Link from somewhere else

Tags: typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a menu Item that gets its href and label from a different component called NavBar. It works with yarn dev but fails to build. Changing  to  fixes the problem. Passing the href directly fixes the issue too.

This is the Menu Item
This Version works, the commented part will not compile

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

type MenuItemProps = {
    label: string;
    href: string;
  };

const MenuItem: React.FC<MenuItemProps> = ({ label, href }) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const isActive = router.pathname === href;
    return (
        <div className={`${"menuItem"} ${isActive ? "menuItem active" : ''}`}>
            {/* <Link href={href}>{label}</Link> */}
            <Link href='/datenschutz'>{label}</Link>
        </div>
  );
};

export default MenuItem;
```

This is the NavBar

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from './MenuItem';

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="navbar">
        <MenuItem href='/leistungen' label='Leistungen'></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem href='/kontakt' label='Kontakt'></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem href='/aktuelles' label='Aktuelles'></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem href='/datenschutz' label='Datenschutz'></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem href='/impressum' label='Impressum'></MenuItem>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Changing `<Link>` to `a` fixes the problem. Passing the href directly fixes the issue too (But this is obviously not practical). I want the functionality of the Link Component for fast navigation on my page. But now I think I can exclude problems with the router.

Comment: It's probably an issue of types. Can you post the error message from the build process?

Comment: What version of NextJs are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `Nav & MenuItem` components are both outside of `pages` directory

Adding non-pages e.g. components to your pages folder can make the build process of passing props fail while works fine in development

reference: [NEXT docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error)